# the text isn't being displayed inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://spencedesign.netau.net/singaporehomemenu.html This is my website. You will see that when you click on that square and then mouse over one of the links on the menu, that the text describing it is not being displayed inline, and I have is to be Display: Inline; in the css. I have scrutinized the code, and can't find the issue. I know the code is really messy, I am going to clean it up, as it probably only looks formatted in my browser, with my screen pixels. If anyone has any tips for making the website look the same in all browsers and screen sizes it would greatly be appreciated. But my main question is about the inline display. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't link to your website. Put all relevant code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and link to that so we can see the code.

Comment: what are you talking about? the text is white on white when not hovering....

Comment: please learn better css first, download a good xgml web template, at the first time copy it, and later try to clone it and see to css only if you have a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span is set as absolute positioned. You need to specify a width and height to carry on with that styling.